# Добавление проверки на спец символы react

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, reactjs

хочу сделать проверку в поиске на спец символы.
Запретить ввод спец символов при поиске на странице.
Реализация с помощью `regexp` - все что не буква или цифра (и пробел) вводить нельзя.

Я только начала изучение React и не могу понять как дописать с useState правильно.

Объявляю state

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState();
```

Поиск:

```
const inputChangeHandler = e => {
    const regexp = /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g;
    const rawValue = e.target.value;
    const trimmedValue = rawValue.trim();
    searchByName(trimmedValue.toLowerCase());
    if (regexp.test(trimmedValue)) { //проверка
      console.log('Да'); 
      const newInputValue = setInputValue(inputValue);
      console.log(newInputValue);
    }
  };
```

Код Input'a

```
<input
type="text"
value={inputValue}
autoFocus={false}
className={styles.gameSearchInput}
onChange={inputChangeHandler}
placeholder='Поиск'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newInputValue = setInputValue(inputValue);
```

Здесь вы создаете константу и присваиваете ей функцию изменения состояния, зачем?

Если ваша проверка прошла, то установка состояния будет `setInputValue(trimmedValue)`, без всяких присваиваний:

```
if (regexp.test(trimmedValue)) { 
  setInputValue(trimmedValue);
}
```